# Prove that the sequence $ x_{n+2}=\frac{4x_{n+1}^{3}-x_{n+1}^{2}x_{n}}{x_{n+1}x_{n} +x_{n}^{2}} $ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction

Let $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence, defined by $x_{1}=6, x_{2}=7$ and
$$
x_{n+2}=\frac{4x_{n+1}^{3}-x_{n+1}^{2}x_{n}}{x_{n+1}x_{n} +x_{n}^{2}}
$$
Prove that this sequence is strictly increasing. I know that I have to prove that $x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}>0$, but I don't know how.

My attempt:

$$x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=\frac{4x_{n+1}^{3}-x_{n+1}^{2}x_{n}}{x_{n+1}x_{n} +x_{n}^{2}}-\frac{4x_{n}^{3}-x_{n}^{2}x_{n-1}}{x_{n}x_{n-1} +x_{n-1}^{2}}
$$
And now I need to show that this is $>0$.

Comment: yes, i ment a sequence

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck in trying to prove $x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}>0$ ?

Comment: When I make $x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}$, $x_{n-1}$ apperes which only complicates the equation. Mabe it is easier to find $x_{n}$ , but I don't know how for this type of sequence.

Comment: Edit your question and show the expression you got that you find complicated. Then, I'll show how to solve this question.

Comment: ok I will edit it

Comment: I found $x_{3}$ too ,but it doesn't help, and $x_{3}-x_{2}>0$, but i can't verify this way for every number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you evaluate $x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}$, you don't have to substitute $x_{n+1}$, we can get a simpler formula just by substituting $x_{n+2}$.

For an induction proof, it's clear that $x_2 > x_1$. Now, assume that for some fixed $n\geq 2$, we have $x_{n+1}>x_n$, and we will prove that $x_{n+2}>x_{n+1}$, that is $x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}>0$. Notice that, using $x_{n+1}-x_n>0$, we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}&=\frac{4x_{n+1}^{3}-x_{n+1}^{2}x_{n}}{x_{n+1}x_{n} +x_{n}^{2}}-x_{n+1}\\
&=\frac{4x_{n+1}^{3}-2x_{n+1}^{2}x_{n}-x_n^2x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}x_{n}+x_n^2}\\
&=\frac{x_{n+1}^3+2x_{n+1}^2(x_{n+1}-x_n)+x_{n+1}(x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2)}{x_{n+1}x_{n}+x_n^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

and this is stricly positive, because $x_{n+1}-x_n>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot that I can use induction that way!